# Error ClassNotFoundException in jar file Maven Java app

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm having an error when I try to package my app. It works perfectly if a run the app without packaging. I read lot of posts having the same problem but any solution is working for me. I'm trying to upload my server-side app into the server.

I'm a bit new in java spring boot.

The pom.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>GastosApp</groupId>
<artifactId>GastosApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>Gastos.Application</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <mainClass>Gastos.Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>Gastos.Application</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

I read that the problem could be in my main Class, because is an implementation of the CommandLineRunner interface. But I need that.

Any suggestion?

Thanks all.

**EDDITED**

The Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Users found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (User user : repository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: First hint never mix versions of spring-boot parts...cause your parent has 2.0.3.RELEASE where as your spring-boot-starter-security has 2.0.4.RELEASE...furthermore why are you defining persistence-api with a version? Is defined by the spring-boot parent...(If I correctly remember)...Apart from that why are you using maven-assembly-plugin? The spring-boot-maven-plugin will handle that...BTW: Without the code of your main class it's really hard to say something ?...

Comment: Which class is not Found?

Comment: @xyz Main Class

Comment: could you please add some stacktrace

Comment: @khmarbaise ok I added the main Class.

Answer (score 0):

You should not package Springboot application by yourself. Springboot provided a Maven plugin for package. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create new class which will implement the CommandLineRunner and mark this class as a component.